In search of: The Lexicon of Exekias/Ezekias
I caught part of a TV segment that was featuring classical sources, the narrator mentioned one text he referred to as "The Lexicon of Exekias"
I jotted it down, thinking it would be easy to find online, however I couldn't find any trace of this text -- even on the oh-so-highly appraised Perseus Tufts. As I was transcribing what I heard on the TV, I can't guarantee that "Exekias" is the right spelling. For good measure, I also searched for "Ezekias" and "Hexikias" and "Hezekias" and also '-ius" endings. But all I could find was texts related to the Septuagint and the artisan potter Exekias, both of which are not what I'm looking for.
The only further details I can offer to help is that it was rather large: each letter of the Greek alphabet had thousands of entries in this lexicon. I don't recall what time period it was allegedly from, but, and this is super important, it must have been late Hellenistic or Early Byzantine.
Perhaps it is not on Perseus Tufts because it is too large, but I'm speculating.
Question
As I've often lamented, modern search engines don't index ancient texts very well, so it is possible that this source does exist, it's just that:

the algo looks past it
or it does not have a digitized format
or my spelling is entirely wrong

Could someone provide affirmation one way or the other that this text does exist and it's correct spelling and date?
From there I may see if I can retrieve an institutional copy in physical format, if it truly doesn't exist online.

I think this is most likely to be the lexicon of Hesychius, titled "Συναγωγὴ Πασῶν Λεξέων κατὰ Στοιχεῖον" or "The Alphabetical Collection of All Words".
Hesychius of Alexandria was a Greek grammarian of the 5th century AD, who wrote his lexicon based partly on other sources no longer surviving. According to his introduction, he used the work of Diogenianus of Heraclea, who himself drew from from the first-century lexicon by Pamphilus of Alexandria. In modern times his name might also be rendered as "Esichio" (Italian, important because the lexicon manuscript is in Venice) or "Hēsýchios" (closer to the Greek spelling).
As described by Peter Allen Hansen,

Approximately 51,000 entries make it the richest surviving Greek lexicon compiled until the invention of printing. It is of great importance to Ancient Greek studies because it contains countless words and expressions from poetry, administration, medicine, and so on, that are otherwise unknown or insufficiently explained. In particular, numerous words from the Greek dialects are important, not only for Greek but also for Indo-European philology.

The work survives through a single fifteenth-century manuscript in the Biblioteca Marciana in Venice, "Marc. Gr. 622". There is also an early printed edition from Aldus Manutius, and a much more recent scholarly edition from the Royal Danish Academy.
I don't think there is a digital version of the original, but hopefully you now have enough breadcrumbs to track down an edition that's accessible to you.

This indeed the source I was looking for, thank you!!
